# ColdFusion 11 update 14 OS migration

Tags: windows, coldfusion

Currently we have servers running on Coldfusion 11 Update 14 and the windows version is 2008 R2. Our company is planning to migrate from windows 2008 to 2016. Does CF 11 update 14 servers support windows 2016?

Thank you.

Comment: Windows 2016 is not listed in the official support matrix - [CF 11 support matrix](https://wwwimages2.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/products/coldfusion/pdfs/cf11/coldfusion11-support-matrix.pdf)  Might not matter anyway as ColdFusion 11 EOL is 04/30/2019 anyway.  Also, ColdFusion 11 is now on update 15. FYI.

Answer (score 1):

According to the comments in this [Adobe blog from 2017](https://coldfusion.adobe.com/2017/04/coldfusion-2016-support-for-windows-server-2016/), CF11 does not support Windows Server 2016:

> *HariKrishna Kallae says:*
>   *May 2, 2017 at 8:22 pm*
>
> Regarding CF11 support for Windows Server 2016 support, there are no plans as of now.

Given that the [support matrix](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/products/coldfusion/pdfs/cf11/coldfusion11-support-matrix.pdf) still doesn't include Windows Server 2016 and ["End of Core Support" is looming on 4/30/2019](https://coldfusion.adobe.com/2017/04/coldfusion-2016-support-for-windows-server-2016/) (as Miguel-F pointed out) I'd say it probably never will.

Comment: @Miguel-F - Sorry... would've posted this as a comment, but not enough rep on serverfault yet...

Comment: Heh.. looks like *now* it lets me post comments. Must've been a delay in updating the account.

Comment: No worries @Ageax. +1 so you have more cred here